# Get value from SQL database

Tags: php, sql, database

I am trying to get a series of 'titles' from a database, and place them in an array as individual strings for each title. Currently I am using this code

```
mysql_select_db($database_Algorox_Build, $Algorox_Build);
$query_getLatest = "SELECT title FROM news ORDER BY title ASC";
$getLatest = mysql_query($query_getLatest, $Algorox_Build) or die(mysql_error());

$totalRows_getLatest = mysql_num_rows($getLatest);

$latestNews = array();

for ($i = 0; $i <= $totalRows_getLatest; ++$i) {
    $row_getLatest = mysql_fetch_assoc($getLatest);
    $latestNews[] = array_values($row_getLatest);
}
```

and when I call them individually using

echo $latestNews[0][0];

I get the string value.

However, I would like to place these strings in to a single array, thereby generating an array of strings. I have tried this:

```
$latestNews = array();
$extractNews = array();

for ($i = 0; $i <= $totalRows_getLatest; ++$i) {
    $row_getLatest = mysql_fetch_assoc($getLatest);
    $latestNews[] = array_values($row_getLatest);
    $extractNews[] = $latestNews[i][0];
}
```

but it doesn't return the string in the output extractNews array.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: So you want an array with a flat hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't really matter what order in the new array, just as long as they are individual strings for each title, and contained in a single array

Comment: In your last bit of code, you have $latestNews[i][0], should probably be $i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
mysql_select_db($database_Algorox_Build, $Algorox_Build);
$query_getLatest = "SELECT title FROM news ORDER BY title ASC";
$getLatest = mysql_query($query_getLatest, $Algorox_Build) or die(mysql_error());

$latestNews = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getLatest)) {
   $latestNews[] = $row['title'];
}
echo "<pre>" . print_r($latestNews,1) . "</pre>";
```

**WATCH OUT**

Please do not use the mysql_* functions anymore. They are deprecated and won't be supported in >= php 5.5. Switch to [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).